# How to switch from VGA to SVGA in OS programming

Tags: c, operating-system, low-level, hdmi, vga

I'm trying to understand all OS theory. But here a problem, I can't find any information on the net to switch in SVGA (or HDMI) to draw on a monitor. I already know we have 4x4096 KB allocated as video memory for VGA but really, it's limited if we want 1080x720 resolution. So
 - How to switch to SVGA (or HDMI) ? Probably a syscall or I/O request ?
 - After that, how to re-define the address of the video memory ?
 - Bonus question : how to use the technology of accelerated hardware ?

Thank you in advance for your answer and sorry for my eventuals wrongs in English

Comment: see for example http://www.svgalib.org/jay/beginners_guide/beginners_guide.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only common low-level standard for resolutions bigger than VGA is VESA BIOS Extensions (VBE). I don't know how widely it's covered with the UEFI backward compatibility, because it's almost never used nowadays.

BIOS Extensions are like drivers built into the card itself. To switch the video mode, or to have pointer to VRAM, you have to call the proper VBE service via it's interrupt. The ROM "driver", designed to work with a certain hardware, performs the needed operations and returns the result.

Unfortunately, no hardware acceleration were covered by VBE, so they became more and more obsolete as GPU became more and more important. No suitable replacement was developed, so if you want to work with bare hardware, you must know **every** video chip (or, at least, a chip family if they're close enough) and write a driver for each one. If PDFs are free, it's easy (I've worked with 3dfx, it's simple: write to the port N, wait until bit R on port M becomes 1 etc).

The problem is, you have to do it for every chip.

You can also read some Linux driver sources, if you want to see how all those ports and I/O are triggered.